# Does "crictl" support pull multiple images in one command and how I use it?

Tags: docker, shell

If I want to pull multiple images, I must use several command as follows.

```
crictl pull nginx && crictl pull ghcr.io/xxx/xxx && crictl pull gcr.io/xxx/xxx
```

My question is can crictl support pull multiple images in one command?

```
crictl pull nginx, ghcr.io/xxx/xxx, gcr.io/xxx/xxx
```

`crictl pull nginx, ghcr.io/xxx/xxx, gcr.io/xxx/xxx` and `crictl pull nginx ghcr.io/xxx/xxx gcr.io/xxx/xxx` not work.

Comment: No it can't. As of right now, `crictl pull` works as outlined here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/8ac1e30c1ac19d1b2c77cb2f22b659c92bd39031/cmd/crictl/image.go#L49. This is similar to dicker or podman, `pull` can only pull a single image.